# When using R's duplicated function to remove duplicates from a data frame, can I select which duplicate row I want to keep?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data-wrangling

I am trying to rid my R data frame of duplicates.
Currently, my code says, if row 1 and 3 have the same column A value, remove the entire row.
I still want to do this, however, I want to specify that the row with "French" in column B is the duplicate row to remove; not the other row, which is identical except that its column B value is "English" (I want to keep the "English" duplicate).

Example data frame code:

```
A <- c(10, 10, 60, 90)
B <- c("French", "English", "English", "English")
C <- c("Civil", "Civil", "Common", "Common")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I have tried:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df$A), ]
```

But I believe this removes the first row by default, whereas, I want to remove the duplicate row that contains "French" in column B.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the dataset so that 'French' always comes last within the `A` group, you can then make sure it is removed when de`duplicated`:

```
df <- df[order(df$A, df$B == "French"),]
df[!duplicated(df$A), ] 
#   A       B      C
#2 10 English  Civil
#3 60 English Common
#4 90 English Common
```

Comment: Would I not have to input a parameter not shown in your code to specify that the "French" values should be put last?

Comment: @bmogil -  It's in there - `df$B == "French"` will return `TRUE` whenever the value is "French", which will be ordered *after* `FALSE` - e.g.: `order(c(TRUE,FALSE))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what logic you are trying to follow-- Are you trying to remove all duplicates that say French? Or are you trying to remove the first duplicate rather than the second duplicate? If the latter, can change the duplicated argument to say, "fromLast = TRUE"

```
A <- c(10, 10, 60, 90)
B <- c("French", "English", "English", "English")
C <- c("Civil", "Civil", "Common", "Common")

df <- data.frame(A,B,C)

df <- df[!duplicated(df$A, fromLast = T), ]
```

If you want to do something like remove the duplicates that are French, maybe something like this? This says select all observations that are NOT French AND duplicates:

```
df[!(df$B == "French" & (duplicated(df$A) | duplicated(df$A, fromLast=TRUE))),]
```

This part "(duplicated(df$A) | duplicated(df$A, fromLast=TRUE)))" is saying to return TRUE for ALL duplicates. If you do duplicated(df$A), it will be FALSE for first duplicate and TRUE for the ones after, and fromLast=T, reverses it. Doing both returns TRUE for all. Then for ALL duplicates, it identifies which ones are French and removes those.

Comment: @jpsmith Fair. Wrote what I think may be a more scalable version

Comment: @bmogil I think the second code excerpt I shared accomplishes that, right?

Comment: I am trying to get rid of all the duplicate values in column A (by removing one of the rows). Most of the duplicates are duplicates across all columns (which makes things easy) but some duplicated pairs are made up of one row with the value "English" for column B, while the other row has "French" for column B. I need to ensure the French one is deleted and the English one stays. I also don't know if the French one will always be the second one. Sorry if this is unclear, but I hope it helps explain things, if not I can try again. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey @bmogil, can you try running the code I shared? I believe it deletes the duplicates that are French. The second excerpt of code: df[!(df$B == "French" & (duplicated(df$A) | duplicated(df$A, fromLast=TRUE))),]

Comment: Will this work to only delete the French duplicates? Because I still want to keep the non-duplicate French rows. Why the fromLast=TRUE?

Comment: Yes, this part "(duplicated(df$A) | duplicated(df$A, fromLast=TRUE)))" is saying to return TRUE for ALL duplicates. If you do duplicated(df$A), it will be FALSE for first duplicate and TRUE for the ones after, and fromLast=T, reverses it. Doing both returns TRUE for all. Then for ALL duplicates, it identifies which ones are French and removes those. Make sense?

If accepted, please consider accepting my answer! I do believe it should work, removing ANY French duplicates. Try it out and let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, say column `B` could take many values:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(10, 10, 60, 90, 90),
  B = c("French", "English", "English", "French", "German"),
  C = c("Civil", "Civil", "Common", "Common", "Common")
)
```

Define a priority list:

```
priority <- c("English", "French", "German")
```

A `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(df)[, p := match(B, priority)][,.(B = B[which.min(p)]), .(A, C)][]
#>     A      C       B
#> 1: 10  Civil English
#> 2: 60 Common English
#> 3: 90 Common  French
```